# Vim color scheme not showing up properly in Mountain Lion's Terminal.app

Tags: vim, colors, osx-mountain-lion, vimrc

EDIT: See my comment below before investing too much time.

I've read a ton of related questions on SE and have had no success. Everyone elses' problems seem to be solved by changing the terminal to 256 colors, or configuring Vim to use 256 colors.

Here is what I have done:

I've copied the blackboard.vim color scheme into ~/.vim/colors

https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-blackboard

Other color schemes render properly, it's only this one.

`:echo &t_Co` returns `256` in Vim

In bash `echo $TERM` returns `xterm-256color`

My ~/.vimrc is

```
  1 syntax on
  2 set nowrap
  3 set number
  4 set nocp
  5 
  6 " Expand tabs to 4 spaces
  7 set tabstop=4
  8 set shiftwidth=4
  9 set expandtab
 10 
 11 " Color scheme with black tweaked from xoria256
 12 " colo sublime
 13 
 14 " Color scheme I like a bit better :)
 15 colo blackboard
```

This is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: Correct]

This is what mine looks like:
[image: Mine]

But my other color scheme renders properly:
[image: Other color scheme]

Comment: I might have just found the answer, but I'd still like to see if anyone else has any ideas. The theme's download page mentions `Only works in gui mode for now` and I'm running from the terminal. So... it's probably a matter of finding a version that is compatible or making one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. This is a GUI scheme.

You could try the [CSApprox plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) (there are a couple of others but that's the only one I can think of at the moment) to convert it to work in a terminal.

However, tis colorscheme is quite short so you could customize it by hand. Adding `cterm[fg|bg]` with a correct value to every line that contains `gui[fg|bg]` should be enough and not take more than 10 minutes:

```
highlight Normal guifg=White guibg=#0B1022 ctermfg=15 ctermbg=232
```

See [this chart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) for the available colors.

Comment: Thanks, when I get some time I think I will try this. If I can make something work I'll probably contact one of the existing theme creators on github and see if they want to merge.

Answer (score 1):

If your terminal support high-color mode as yours, you can use the [CSApprox plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) to automatically convert a GUI-only colorscheme for the console.